# Missing Containers Cmdlet

Tags: powershell, containers, windows-server-2016

I created the new Server Core (Windows 2016). I can't find the all container cmdlet in powershell. I did Uninstall/installed the containers feature but still missing all cmdlet. How do i get containers cmdlet in powershell?

Here is my server info.

```
WindowsBuildLabEx                                       : 16299.15.amd64fre.rs3_release.170928-1534
WindowsCurrentVersion                                   : 6.3
WindowsEditionId                                        : ServerDatacenterACor
WindowsInstallationType                                 : Server Core
WindowsInstallDateFromRegistry                          : 28/4/2018 12:41:19 PM
WindowsProductId                                        : 00395-60000-00001-AA842
WindowsProductName                                      : Windows Server Datacenter
WindowsRegisteredOrganization                           : 
WindowsRegisteredOwner                                  : Windows User
WindowsSystemRoot                                       : C:\Windows
WindowsVersion                                          : 1709
BiosCharacteristics                                     : {3, 9, 15, 16...}
BiosBIOSVersion                                         : {VRTUAL - 1, Hyper-V UEFI Release v2.5, Microsoft - 100032}
BiosBuildNumber                                         : 
BiosCaption                                             : Hyper-V UEFI Release v2.5
BiosCodeSet                                             : 
BiosCurrentLanguage                                     : 
BiosDescription                                         : Hyper-V UEFI Release v2.5
BiosEmbeddedControllerMajorVersion                      : 255
BiosEmbeddedControllerMinorVersion                      : 255
BiosFirmwareType                                        : Uefi
BiosIdentificationCode                                  : 
BiosInstallableLanguages                                : 
BiosInstallDate                                         : 
BiosLanguageEdition                                     : 
BiosListOfLanguages                                     : 
BiosManufacturer                                        : Microsoft Corporation
BiosName                                                : Hyper-V UEFI Release v2.5
BiosOtherTargetOS                                       : 
BiosPrimaryBIOS                                         : True
BiosReleaseDate                                         : 22/8/2017 8:00:00 AM
BiosSeralNumber                                         : 8355-6248-8581-2148-3845-5374-58
BiosSMBIOSBIOSVersion                                   : Hyper-V UEFI Release v2.5
BiosSMBIOSMajorVersion                                  : 2
BiosSMBIOSMinorVersion                                  : 4
BiosSMBIOSPresent                                       : True
BiosSoftwareElementState                                : Running
BiosStatus                                              : OK
BiosSystemBiosMajorVersion                              : 2
BiosSystemBiosMinorVersion                              : 5
BiosTargetOperatingSystem                               : 0
BiosVersion                                             : VRTUAL - 1
CsAdminPasswordStatus                                   : Unknown
CsAutomaticManagedPagefile                              : True
CsAutomaticResetBootOption                              : True
CsAutomaticResetCapability                              : True
CsBootOptionOnLimit                                     : 
CsBootOptionOnWatchDog                                  : 
CsBootROMSupported                                      : True
CsBootStatus                                            : {0, 0, 0, 127...}
CsBootupState                                           : Normal boot
CsCaption                                               : WIN16DCORE
CsChassisBootupState                                    : Safe
CsChassisSKUNumber                                      : 
CsCurrentTimeZone                                       : 480
CsDaylightInEffect                                      : 
CsDescription                                           : AT/AT COMPATIBLE
CsDNSHostName                                           : WIN16DCore
CsDomain                                                : WORKGROUP
CsDomainRole                                            : StandaloneServer
CsEnableDaylightSavingsTime                             : True
CsFrontPanelResetStatus                                 : Unknown
CsHypervisorPresent                                     : True
CsInfraredSupported                                     : False
CsInitialLoadInfo                                       : 
CsInstallDate                                           : 
CsKeyboardPasswordStatus                                : Unknown
CsLastLoadInfo                                          : 
CsManufacturer                                          : Microsoft Corporation
CsModel                                                 : Virtual Machine
CsName                                                  : WIN16DCORE
CsNetworkAdapters                                       : {vEthernet - 1}
CsNetworkServerModeEnabled                              : True
CsNumberOfLogicalProcessors                             : 1
CsNumberOfProcessors                                    : 1
CsProcessors                                            : {Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2100 CPU @ 3.10GHz}
CsOEMStringArray                                        : {[MS_VM_CERT/SHA1/9b80ca0d5dd061ec9da4e494f4c3fd1196270c22], 
                                                          00000000000000000000000000000000, To be filled by OEM}
CsPartOfDomain                                          : False
CsPauseAfterReset                                       : -1
CsPCSystemType                                          : Desktop
CsPCSystemTypeEx                                        : Desktop
CsPowerManagementCapabilities                           : 
CsPowerManagementSupported                              : 
CsPowerOnPasswordStatus                                 : Unknown
CsPowerState                                            : Unknown
CsPowerSupplyState                                      : Safe
CsPrimaryOwnerContact                                   : 
CsPrimaryOwnerName                                      : Windows User
CsResetCapability                                       : Other
CsResetCount                                            : -1
CsResetLimit                                            : -1
CsRoles                                                 : {LM_Workstation, LM_Server, NT, Server_NT}
CsStatus                                                : OK
CsSupportContactDescription                             : 
CsSystemFamily                                          : Virtual Machine
CsSystemSKUNumber                                       : None
CsSystemType                                            : x64-based PC
CsThermalState                                          : Safe
CsTotalPhysicalMemory                                   : 5082476544
CsPhyicallyInstalledMemory                              : 4964352
CsUserName                                              : 
CsWakeUpType                                            : PowerSwitch
CsWorkgroup                                             : WORKGROUP
OsName                                                  : Microsoft Windows Server Datacenter
OsType                                                  : WINNT
OsOperatingSystemSKU                                    : 145
OsVersion                                               : 10.0.16299
OsCSDVersion                                            : 
OsBuildNumber                                           : 16299
OsHotFixes                                              : {KB4099989, KB4093112}
OsBootDevice                                            : \Device\HarddiskVolume2
OsSystemDevice                                          : \Device\HarddiskVolume4
OsSystemDirectory                                       : C:\Windows\system32
OsSystemDrive                                           : C:
OsWindowsDirectory                                      : C:\Windows
OsCountryCode                                           : 65
OsCurrentTimeZone                                       : 480
OsLocaleID                                              : 4809
OsLocale                                                : en-SG
OsLocalDateTime                                         : 29/4/2018 1:35:42 PM
OsLastBootUpTime                                        : 29/4/2018 1:23:23 PM
OsUptime                                                : 00:12:18.3221697
OsBuildType                                             : Multiprocessor Free
OsCodeSet                                               : 1252
OsDataExecutionPreventionAvailable                      : True
OsDataExecutionPrevention32BitApplications              : True
OsDataExecutionPreventionDrivers                        : True
OsDataExecutionPreventionSupportPolicy                  : OptOut
OsDebug                                                 : False
OsDistributed                                           : False
OsEncryptionLevel                                       : 256
OsForegroundApplicationBoost                            : Maximum
OsTotalVisibleMemorySize                                : 4963356
OsFreePhysicalMemory                                    : 4239756
OsTotalVirtualMemorySize                                : 6536220
OsFreeVirtualMemory                                     : 5858416
OsInUseVirtualMemory                                    : 677804
OsTotalSwapSpaceSize                                    : 
OsSizeStoredInPagingFiles                               : 1572864
OsFreeSpaceInPagingFiles                                : 1572864
OsPagingFiles                                           : {C:\pagefile.sys}
OsHardwareAbstractionLayer                              : 10.0.16299.371
OsInstallDate                                           : 28/4/2018 8:41:19 PM
OsManufacturer                                          : Microsoft Corporation
OsMaxNumberOfProcesses                                  : 4294967295
OsMaxProcessMemorySize                                  : 137438953344
OsMuiLanguages                                          : {en-US}
OsNumberOfLicensedUsers                                 : 0
OsNumberOfProcesses                                     : 66
OsNumberOfUsers                                         : 2
OsOrganization                                          : 
OsArchitecture                                          : 64-bit
OsLanguage                                              : en-US
OsProductSuites                                         : {TerminalServices, TerminalServicesSingleSession}
OsOtherTypeDescription                                  : 
OsPAEEnabled                                            : 
OsPortableOperatingSystem                               : False
OsPrimary                                               : True
OsProductType                                           : Server
OsRegisteredUser                                        : Windows User
OsSerialNumber                                          : 00395-60000-00001-AA842
OsServicePackMajorVersion                               : 0
OsServicePackMinorVersion                               : 0
OsStatus                                                : OK
OsSuites                                                : {TerminalServices, TerminalServicesSingleSession}
OsServerLevel                                           : ServerCore
KeyboardLayout                                          : en-US
TimeZone                                                : (UTC+08:00) Kuala Lumpur, Singapore
LogonServer                                             : 
PowerPlatformRole                                       : Desktop
HyperVisorPresent                                       : True
HyperVRequirementDataExecutionPreventionAvailable       : 
HyperVRequirementSecondLevelAddressTranslation          : 
HyperVRequirementVirtualizationFirmwareEnabled          : 
HyperVRequirementVMMonitorModeExtensions                : 
DeviceGuardSmartStatus                                  : Off
DeviceGuardRequiredSecurityProperties                   : 
DeviceGuardAvailableSecurityProperties                  : 
DeviceGuardSecurityServicesConfigured                   : 
DeviceGuardSecurityServicesRunning                      : 
DeviceGuardCodeIntegrityPolicyEnforcementStatus         : 
DeviceGuardUserModeCodeIntegrityPolicyEnforcementStatus :
```

Here is cmdlet to find the container cmdlet and result

```
Get-WindowsFeature -Name Containers
Display Name                                            Name                       Install State
------------                                            ----                       -------------
[X] Containers                                          Containers                     Installed

Get-InstalledModule
Version    Name                                Repository           Description
-------    ----                                ----------           -----------
1.0.0.4    DockerMsftProvider                  PSGallery            PowerShell module with commands for discovering,...
1.0.154    DockerPowershell                    PSGallery            Adds cmdlets to work with the Docker cli.

get-command | where Source -EQ "*cont*"
Empty
```

Comment: When you installed the feature did you include the management tools? e.g. `Install-WindowsFeature Containers -IncludeManagementTools`

Comment: I did uninstall container and install with -IncludeManagementTools. But still same result.